# SQL Trigger Updating a different table when the data changes in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two tables: one that contains products and another one that has the order information.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ORDERS] 
  ( 
     [ROW]           [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
     [ID]            [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL, 
     [RETAILER_ID]   [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL, 
     [INDIVIDUAL_ID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL, 
     [PRODUCT_ID]    [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL, 
     [QUANTITY]      [BIGINT] NOT NULL, 
     [DATE]          [DATETIME] NOT NULL, 
     [MEMO]          [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL 
  ) 
ON [PRIMARY] 
TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY] 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCTS] 
  ( 
     [ROW]         [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
     [ID]          [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL, 
     [RETAILER_ID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL, 
     [NAME]        [NVARCHAR](255) NOT NULL 
  ) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

We need to fix this Trigger so that when a name of a product changes, the memo field in the orders table needs to have a remark about that change in the orders table. So here is the trigger that we designed but we are getting errors "The multi-part identifier "o.Memo" could not be bound."

Here is the trigger that generates errors? Where did we go wrong?

```
CREATE TRIGGER DBO.PRODUCTS_NAME_CHG 
ON DBO.PRODUCTS 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from 
      -- interfering with SELECT statements. 
      DECLARE @old NVARCHAR(255), 
              @new NVARCHAR(255), 
              @ID  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 

      SELECT @ID = ID, 
             @old = NAME 
      FROM   DELETED 

      SELECT @NEW = NAME 
      FROM   INSERTED 

      SET NOCOUNT ON; 

      IF UPDATE (NAME) 
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE DBO.ORDERS 
            SET    o.MEMO = o.MEMO + ' ' + @OLD + ' HAS CHANGED NAME TO ' + @NEW 
                            + '. ' 
            FROM   ORDERS o 
                   INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P 
                           ON P.ID = O.PRODUCT_ID 
            WHERE  P.ID = @ID 
        END 
  END 

GO
```

Comment: Never assume that there will always be one record in `inserted` and `deleted` tables. Sql Server fires triggers once per statement, not per row, so this trigger will fail to notice change of name if you decide to update bunch of records at once. The join of `inserted`, `deleted` and base table will produce all the info you need to update base table.

Comment: `if update(name)` does not ensure that name has changed; it merely expresses that `name` took part in update query. This will prove problematic if you work with an ORM that updates **all** the columns. Use `where inserted.name <> deleted.name` in update query in addition to `if update(name)` test. If name is nullable you will have to devise more complicated criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the syntax for an update with an inner join should be

```
UPDATE o -- use alias here, not table name.
  SET o.Memo = --blabla
  FROM Orders o
  INNER JOIN --blabla
```